# Custom virtual binding handler not working

Tags: knockout.js

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xH3mh/6/

I'm trying to fade the whole list away with a virtual `fadeVisible` - I can't use a container element, so previously I was using a structure like this:

```
<!-- ko if: show -->
<!-- ko foreach: items() -->
<div data-bind="text: name"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Now, I have this:

```
<!-- ko fadeVisible: show -->
<!-- ko foreach: items() -->
<div data-bind="text: name"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

With the following `bindingHandler`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)); // Use "unwrapObservable" so we can handle values that may or may not be observable
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();
        }
    };  

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.fadeVisible = true;
```

But this is not working for some reason.  Locally I get this error:

> Unable to process binding "fadeVisible: function (){return show() }"
>   Message: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined

on JSFiddle I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
```

If I use the `getFirstRealElement` function to capture the first element and use that in place of `element`, it works, but I need the whole list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fadeOut/In a virtual element. Because a virtual element is not associated to dom element.

What you attempt to do is like using the visible binding to an virtual element. If you do that you will get this error :

```
The binding 'visible' cannot be used with virtual elements.
```

The reason is, the visible binding and your fadeOut binding try modify a dom element ($(element).show() and $(element).fadeIn()), which doesn't exists.

So if you want to have fadeOut/In transition you can't use an virtual element.

In brief  : bindings which modify the style of an element and not its flow can't be applied to virtual element.